# Show value in textbox based on dropdown selection

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to show values in the textbox based on select values. For example, If I select a customer name from the select element, then his detail like address, the phone number needs to be dynamically filled in those textboxes

Here is MySQL table

Table Name: Customer

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpF6G.png)

MYSQL and PHP

```
<?php
$select_customer = "select * from customer";
$select_customer_query = mysqli_query($connection, $select_customer); // Customer Data
?>

      <form method="post" action="">
      <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" name="customer_name">
      <option>Customer Name</option>
      <?php while($customer_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_customer_query)) { ?>
      <option><?php echo $customer_result['name']; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
      </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Website">
      </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: What did you tried ? Some javascript ?

Comment: I know this will be achieved with the help of jquery and ajax! 

but I'm not very good when it comes to jquery @The_Death_Raw

Comment: Use JQuery AJAX or if you're not very comfortable with jquery use javascript [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to fetch data against selected customer name, and populate the form accordingly.

Comment: You'll have to use `onchange="methodName()"` on select, to get value of the selected option.

Comment: Thank you @HassanMalik I figured it out!

Comment: @shaktigoyal Please consider answering your own question in the interests of helping anyone who may have the same issue as you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **onChange** to get the value when selected value changed

For getting values like phone number and website you can add other values as attribute to option and get then on change

Now when **onChange** Called you need to get that attribute values from selected option and set them in text boxes using jQuery

```
  <form method="post" action="">
      <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" name="customer_name">
      <option>Customer Name</option>
      <?php while($customer_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_customer_query)) { ?>
      <option website="<?php echo $customer_result['website']; ?>" phone_number="<?php echo $customer_result['phone_number']; ?>" ><?php echo $customer_result['name']; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
      </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <input id="phone_number" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <input id="website" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Website">
      </div>
      </form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {     
$('select[name="customer_name"]').change(function(){
   var website = $('option:selected', this).attr('website');
   $("#website").val(website);
   var phone_number = $('option:selected', this).attr('phone_number');
   $("#phone_number").val(phone_number);
});
});
</script>
```

> `$('select[name="customer_name"]').change(function(){})`

here it will detect the change by selecting that element using its name

```
`
```

> $('option:selected', this).attr('website');

` this will get attribute by name we pass in it like currently website from selected option